# Error when creating a grand total of a basket

Tags: php

I am getting an error regarding an undefined variable. However, the calculation is correct and it displays the grand total but the error still appears within the page - here is the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: grand_total in
```

And here is my code:

```
$line_cost = $product['price'] * $item['quantity'];
  $grand_total += $line_cost;

  ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?=$product['common_name'];?></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value='<?=$item['quantity'];?>' size='2' /></td>
    <td>&pound;<?=number_format($line_cost, 2);?></td>
  </tr>
  <!---
    Notice the [] on the field name for quantity - this means it is an array
    The index of the array will start at 0 (i,e. the first product) and the second will be 1, etc...
  --->
  <?php

}
?>
  <!-- Final row to put a button to recalculate -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3' align='center'>
      <input type='submit' name='recalc' value='Recalculate' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&pound;<?=number_format($grand_total, 2);?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `$grand_total` variable not defined above.

```
$grand_total = isset($grand_total) ? $grand_total : 0;
$line_cost = $product['price'] * $item['quantity'];
$grand_total += $line_cost;
```

Also you can change error reporting to not show notice/warning with [error_reporting()](http://az.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks but thats weird because now I have done that, the error has disappeared but it is displaying the last line cost instead of the grand total

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks matey ur the best